# is the bes way to get position in angular with async await?

Tags: angular, async-await

This is my code and works fine, but is ugly. My objective is make this in a service. But first when I put async await function doesn't work:

Check this out:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLocation();
  }

  getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.position = position;
        this.makeSomething_1();
        this.makeSomething_3();
        this.makeSomething_4();
      }, positionError => {
        console.log('The user don accept location.');
        this.makeSomething_1();
        this.makeSomething_3();
        this.makeSomething_4();
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
      this.makeSomething_1();
      this.makeSomething_3();
      this.makeSomething_4();
    }
  }
```

But I want to make something like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getLocation();
    this.makeSomething_1();
    this.makeSomething_3();
    this.makeSomething_4();
  }

async getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.position = position;
      }, positionError => {
        console.log('The user don accept location.');
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
    }
  }
```

The problem with I want is is this.position print "undefinied"

Can someone teach me how write good code?

Please don't put me -1. I try my best

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way would be to cache the result in the service using RxJS multi-cast observable like `ReplaySubject`.

Try the following

Service

```js
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

export class LocationService {
  private positionSource = new ReplaySubject(1);    // <-- buffer 1
  public position$ = this.positionSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.getLocation();
  }

  getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.makeSomething_1();
        this.makeSomething_3();
        this.makeSomething_4();
        this.positionSource.next(position);
      }, positionError => {
        console.log('The user don accept location.');
        this.makeSomething_1();
        this.makeSomething_3();
        this.makeSomething_4();
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
      this.makeSomething_1();
      this.makeSomething_3();
      this.makeSomething_4();
    }
  }
}
```

Component

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _location: LocationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._location.position$.subscribe({
      next: position => {
        console.log('Got position: ', position);
        // do something else with `position`
      }
    });
  }
}
```